# slicing multidimensional array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, slice

I am wondering why in Matlab:

```
x = randn(100,100,3,30);
r = x(:,:,1,:);
q = y(:,:,:,1);
```

q is as espected a 100x100x3 double array, while r is a 4-D double.
Any hint?

Comment: I already figured out that I can permute the array, and that solves the problem. Still it's an unexpected behaviour for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `r` is also a 3D array, however the 3rd dimension in the 4D array contains only 1 element, so it's a singleton dimension that can be removed using [squeeze](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html). Matlab does not remove it automatically because it is not the "last" dimension, in contrast to `q`.

In other words,

```
size(r) = 100 100 1 30
```

and

```
size(q) = 100 100 3 1
```

which becomes  `100 100 3` automatically.

Calling `size(squeeze(r))` and `size(squeeze(q))` yields a 3D array in both cases.

Is that a bit clearer?